# Can't install Ubuntu, black screen after install

Tags: installation

I tried several times, but wasn't able to make it work.

I tried all recent types of Ubuntu but it didn't work. Then I tried `acpi=off` at the beginning of the installation. In this way I could finish the installation. But after the restart Ubuntu didn't work. Only a black screen appeared.

Before that I tried it on the VirtualBox and it work.

By the way my system is the following: (I use windows 7 currently)

- Processor AMD Athlon II P320 (2,1 GHz, second-level cache 2 ? 512 KB, HT 1600 MHz bus)
- Chipset AMD M880G + SB850
- Memory Dual Channel, 3 GB DDR3-1066
- Wide Screen 15.6 “high-definition (1366 ? 768) c LED-backlit, AU Optronics B156XW02
- Video Card AMD Radeon HD 4250, from 336 MB video buffer in memory, support for DirectX 10.1 and UVD
- Sound system: HDA-codec IDT 92HD81B1X AMD HDMI Audio
- Hard drive WDC WD3200BEVT-75A23T0 (298 GB, 5400 RPM, SATA 2.0)
- Optical Drive: DVD ± RW Optiarc AD-7585H
- Communication tools Fast Ethernet (10/100 Mbit / c) Realtek RTL8102E/RTL8103E WiFi 802.11a/b/g Broadcom BCM4310 Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR
- Card reader
- Memory Card Reader 7-in-1 with support for SD / SDHC / MMC / MS / xD, and derivatives
- Interfaces / ports 3 USB 2.0 1 eSATA + USB 2.0 15-pin video connector VGA HDMI RJ-45 Ethernet 10/100 Mbit / c 2 analog mini-jack: a microphone / headphone jack for a Kensington lock slot AC adapter
- Battery Li-Ion 6-cell capacity of 4400 mA ? h (10,8, 48 W ? hr) AC power adapter 65 Watt
- Additional equipment integrated web-camera (1.3 mega pixels)

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to boot into (and use) the OS from the live disc? Can you access the recovery command line without problems?

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the GRUB screen to select OS, press <kbd>e</kbd>, then change where it says `quiet splash` to `nomodeset`.